# Null object on incrementer trigger

Tags: trigger, null-pointer, increment

I am trying to increment a field on a parent object Deal__c with every child object Deliverable__c created. My debug shows an id for theDeal but the 
theDeal.DeliverablesIncrementer__c+=1; is getting an "attempt to reference a null object" error
I also want to use the same incremented number on the deliverable itself.

```
trigger DeliverableDealIncrementer on Deliverable__c (after insert) {

    for (Deliverable__c DD : system.trigger.new){
        Deal__c theDeal = [select id,   DeliverablesIncrementer__c from Deal__c where id=: DD.deal__c];
        system.debug('thedeal======================'+theDeal);


        theDeal.DeliverablesIncrementer__c+=1;
        DD.Deal_Deliverable_Decimal_del__c +=1;
    database.update(theDeal,false);

    } 

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that DeliverablesIncrementer__c on the record itself is null, that's why `

```
system.debug('thedeal======================'+theDeal);`
```

shows you only Id. You need to modify your code to check if DeliverablesIncrementer__c is null and if so, just assign it to 1:

```
theDeal.DeliverablesIncrementer__c = (theDeal.DeliverablesIncrementer__c == null) ? 1 : theDeal.DeliverablesIncrementer__c + 1;
```

Comment: Thank you. I added a line to fix the field on the deliverable__c as well. Was not familiar with this notation. I wonder though - is this trigger configured for bulk input, and can it be with the incrementer?

Comment: The trigger in the original post is not configured for bulk, since you're performing a DML and a SOQL operation for each record, it'll be out of limits if you'll try to insert more than 100 records.